# Data to .csv is repeating three times. I need three different scrapes exported to a csv file

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

The csv files are repeating the same information. I need updated information sent to the excel sheet from the three embedded sources. There is code that links the href from the base page to the product review pages. Also, when checking the output from spyder/anaconda python package, everything was coded right. So the problem has to be within the write function. Can anyone please help?

I've tried reformatting the code using a+ and w/w+, but nothing seems to work.

```
import requests as r
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

#Get URL
main_url = 'http://drd.ba.ttu.edu/isqs6339/imbadproducts/'
response = r.get(main_url)

#Set filepaths
filepath = 'dataout1.csv'
filepath2 = 'dataout2.csv'

#Check for good link and get headers
print(response.status_code)
print (response.headers)

soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'lxml')
print(soup.prettify())

#Find all anchors on the page
search_results = soup.find('div', attrs={'id' : 'searchresults'})
product_results = search_results.find_all('a')

#Define product link, id, title, price, and description for all products
for link in product_results:
    link_url = main_url + link.get('href')
    productId = link.find('span', attrs={'class' : 'productid'}).text
    product_title = link.find('span', attrs={'class' : 'producttitle'}).text
    product_price = link.find('span', attrs={'class' : 'productprice'}).text
    product_description = link.find('span', attrs={'class' : 'productdesc'}).text

    #Get links for each product
    response2 = r.get(link_url)
    soup2 = BeautifulSoup(response2.text, 'lxml')
    #Find each user review for the product on the page
    user_review = soup2.find('div', attrs={'id' : 'userreviews'})
    review_results = user_review.find_all('div')
    #Find author, stars, and review info for each review of the page's product and print results
    for rev in review_results:
        print ('ProductID: ' + productId)
        print ('Product Title: ' + product_title)
        print ('Product Price: ' + product_price)
        print('Product Description: ' + product_description)
        print ('User Review: ' )
        author = rev.find('span', attrs={'class' : 'rauthor'}).text
        print('Author: ' + author)
        stars = rev.find('span', attrs={'class' : 'rstars'}).text
        print('Stars: ' + stars)
        review_of_product = rev.find('span' , attrs={'class' : 'rtext'}).text
        print('Review: ' + review_of_product)
        review_length = len(review_of_product)
        print('Length: ')
        print(review_length)
        print('------------')

#Import CSV
import csv

#Open File 1 in CSV File
with open(filepath, 'w') as dataout:
    datawriter = csv.writer(dataout, delimiter= ',', quotechar= '"', quoting = csv.QUOTE_NONNUMERIC)
    headers = ['ProductId', 'Product Title', 'Product Price', 'Author', 'Stars', 'Length of Review']
    datawriter.writerow(headers)

    for link in product_results:
        productId = link.find('span', attrs={'class' : 'productid'}).text
        product_title = link.find('span', attrs={'class' : 'producttitle'}).text
        product_price = link.find('span', attrs={'class' : 'productprice'}).text
        for rev in review_results:    
            author = rev.find('span', attrs={'class' : 'rauthor'}).text
            stars = rev.find('span', attrs={'class' : 'rstars'}).text
            review_of_product = rev.find('span' , attrs={'class' : 'rtext'}).text
            datawriter.writerow([productId, product_title, product_price, author, stars, len(review_of_product)])

#Open File 2 in CSV File
with open(filepath2, 'w') as dataout2:
    datawriter = csv.writer(dataout2, delimiter= ',', quotechar= '"', quoting = csv.QUOTE_NONNUMERIC)
    headers = ['ProductId', 'Author', 'Stars', 'Review Text']
    datawriter.writerow(headers)

    for link in product_results:
        productId = link.find('span', attrs={'class' : 'productid'}).text
        for rev in review_results:    
            author = rev.find('span', attrs={'class' : 'rauthor'}).text
            stars = rev.find('span', attrs={'class' : 'rstars'}).text
            review_of_product = rev.find('span' , attrs={'class' : 'rtext'}).text
            datawriter.writerow([productId, author, stars, review_of_product])
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are looping through the reviews of each link, but OUTSIDE of your loop through the links. So essentially you're only holding on to the last iteration of those reviews. You need to loop through those reviews within each link. So essentially you need it to be a nested loop.

I also fixed the issue with the skipping lines in your csv by adding the parameter `newline=''`

```
import requests as r
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import csv

#Get URL
main_url = 'http://drd.ba.ttu.edu/isqs6339/imbadproducts/'
response = r.get(main_url)

#Set filepaths
filepath = 'dataout1.csv'
filepath2 = 'dataout2.csv'

#Check for good link and get headers
print(response.status_code)
print (response.headers)

soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'lxml')
print(soup.prettify())

#Find all anchors on the page
search_results = soup.find('div', attrs={'id' : 'searchresults'})
product_results = search_results.find_all('a')


with open(filepath, 'w', newline = '') as dataout:
    datawriter = csv.writer(dataout, delimiter= ',', quotechar= '"', quoting = csv.QUOTE_NONNUMERIC)
    headers = ['ProductId', 'Product Title', 'Product Price', 'Author', 'Stars', 'Length of Review']
    datawriter.writerow(headers)
    #Define product link, id, title, price, and description for all products
    for link in product_results:
        link_url = main_url + link.get('href')
        productId = link.find('span', attrs={'class' : 'productid'}).text
        product_title = link.find('span', attrs={'class' : 'producttitle'}).text
        product_price = link.find('span', attrs={'class' : 'productprice'}).text
        product_description = link.find('span', attrs={'class' : 'productdesc'}).text

        response2 = r.get(link_url)
        soup2 = BeautifulSoup(response2.text, 'lxml')
        #Find each user review for the product on the page
        user_review = soup2.find('div', attrs={'id' : 'userreviews'})
        review_results = user_review.find_all('div')

        for rev in review_results:
                author = rev.find('span', attrs={'class' : 'rauthor'}).text
                stars = rev.find('span', attrs={'class' : 'rstars'}).text
                review_of_product = rev.find('span' , attrs={'class' : 'rtext'}).text
                datawriter.writerow([productId, product_title, product_price, author, stars, len(review_of_product)])




#Open File 2 in CSV File
with open(filepath2, 'w', newline = '') as dataout2:
    datawriter = csv.writer(dataout2, delimiter= ',', quotechar= '"', quoting = csv.QUOTE_NONNUMERIC)
    headers = ['ProductId', 'Author', 'Stars', 'Review Text']
    datawriter.writerow(headers)

    for link in product_results:
        link_url = main_url + link.get('href')
        productId = link.find('span', attrs={'class' : 'productid'}).text

        response2 = r.get(link_url)
        soup2 = BeautifulSoup(response2.text, 'lxml')
        #Find each user review for the product on the page
        user_review = soup2.find('div', attrs={'id' : 'userreviews'})
        review_results = user_review.find_all('div')

        for rev in review_results:    
            author = rev.find('span', attrs={'class' : 'rauthor'}).text
            stars = rev.find('span', attrs={'class' : 'rstars'}).text
            review_of_product = rev.find('span' , attrs={'class' : 'rtext'}).text
            datawriter.writerow([productId, author, stars, review_of_product])
```